# How to bold matched letters when typing in search box using javascript?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, searchbar, bold

How can I type within a search box and have the letters I type turn bold from suggested words? For example, I type "he" in search bar and it looks like this as I type: **he**lp. Also, if I type in "lp" the text should appear: he**lp**.

I have some code written already and I just want to add this functionality to it, but not sure how to do this. Thank you.

```js
  // List toggle (search bar)
  const searchBar = document.querySelector('#search-bar');
  const searchList = document.querySelector('#search-list');

  searchBar.addEventListener('click', () => {
    searchList.style.display = "block";
  });

  const updateListState = e => {
    const targetId = e.target.id;
    if (targetId !== 'search-bar' && targetId !== 'search-list' && targetId !== 'search-bar-filler' && targetId !== 'search-bar-container' && targetId !== 'search-item-names' && targetId !== 'search-submit' && targetId !== 'search-submit-container') {
      searchList.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', updateListState);

  // Letter search (search bar)
  function search_items() {
    let input = document.getElementById('search-bar').value
    input = input.toLowerCase();

    let x = document.getElementsByClassName('search-item-names');

    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
      if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
        x[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      else {
        x[i].style.display = "list-item";
      }
    }
  }
```

```css
  #filler {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }

  #search-list {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: none;
  }
```

```html
  <div id="search-bar-container">
    <input id="search-bar" type="text" name="search" onkeyup="search_items()" placeholder="Search items..">
    <div id="search-bar-filler"></div>
    <div id='search-list'>
      <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Automotive Degreaser</div>
      <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Beats by Dre</div>
      <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">JBL Partybox</div>
      <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Makeup</div>
      <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Mr Potato Head</div>
      <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Olympus Camera</div>
      <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Pillow</div>
      <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">RC Race Car</div>
      <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Simon Rabbit</div>
      <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Truth Hoodie</div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about dynamically creating a regular expression based on the user's input and using it to parse and format the matching parts of the suggestions:

```js
const searchBar = document.querySelector('#search-bar');
const searchList = document.querySelector('#search-list');

searchBar.addEventListener('click', () => {
    searchList.style.display = "block";
});

const updateListState = e => {
    const targetId = e.target.id;
    if (targetId !== 'search-bar' && targetId !== 'search-list' && targetId !== 'search-bar-filler' && targetId !== 'search-bar-container' && targetId !== 'search-item-names' && targetId !== 'search-submit' && targetId !== 'search-submit-container') {
        searchList.style.display = "none";
    }
}
document.addEventListener('mousemove', updateListState);

function search_items() {
    let input = document.getElementById('search-bar').value;
    input = input.toLowerCase();
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName('search-item-names');
    const regex = new RegExp(input, 'gi');
    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        let originalText = x[i].getAttribute('data-original-text');
        if (!originalText) {
            originalText = x[i].textContent;
            x[i].setAttribute('data-original-text', originalText);
        }
        if (!originalText.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
            x[i].style.display = "none";
        } else {
            x[i].style.display = "list-item";
            const formattedText = originalText.replace(regex, match => `<b>${match}</b>`);
            x[i].innerHTML = formattedText;
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById('search-bar').addEventListener('input', function () {
    if (this.value === '') {
        search_items();
    }
});
```

```css
#filler {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

#search-list {
    margin-top: 20px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="search-bar-container">
    <input id="search-bar" type="text" name="search" onkeyup="search_items()" placeholder="Search items..">
    <div id="search-bar-filler"></div>
    <div id='search-list'>
        <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Automotive Degreaser</div>
        <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Beats by Dre</div>
        <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">JBL Partybox</div>
        <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Makeup</div>
        <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Mr Potato Head</div>
        <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Olympus Camera</div>
        <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Pillow</div>
        <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">RC Race Car</div>
        <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Simon Rabbit</div>
        <div id="search-item-names" class="search-item-names">Truth Hoodie</div>
    </div>
</div>
```